# How to save data upon refreshing in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I am looking for a formula or at least a solution to the following: how to automatically save past data upon refreshing the query in Power BI?

**Context**: I have a column named "End Date" containing different dates. 
All these dates are of course updated every time I refresh the query.

**The problem** is that these end dates are manually modified in the CRM from where I pull the data; thus when refreshing, I get the latest "end dates" and lose the previous date that was written there.

I would like to somehow be able to store/keep/save the previous dates - the purpose is to count how many times these "end dates" have been modified.

Attached is a picture with the column. Please let me know if what I wrote is clear enough. I will try to reexplain better. 
https://ibb.co/vvmYZNt

Best regards,
Denis

Comment: This is something that you should do in the ETL process when loading data in your model, not in the report itself.

Comment: Hello Andrey! I want to automate this in the ETL actually and be displayed in the report. That s why I am looking for a formula to have it already done.

Comment: ETL process is not part of the Power BI report. Your question is tagged with powerbi, fax and powerquery. None of these is related to the ETL. How it’s made in your environment?